# CUDA exit code 255, and ptxas fatal

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, cuda

I'm having some trouble with CUDA and Visual Studio, when I run the CUDA Debugger it runs the last successfully built code, but when I try to build the project again it outputs: `"...\main.cu" exited with code 255` in the error list, and in the output tab, basically this error: `ptxas fatal   : Unresolved extern function '_ZN7Vector4plERKS_'`

I already checked the other questions, tried googling it, searching on different sites, tried turning the relocatable device to on, but it gave the same error message, except the `ptxas` but with this one:

```
Undefined reference to '_ZN7Vector4plERKS_' in 'x64/Debug/main.cu.obj'
```

Also, I'm using VS2015 and just to be sure: I should first build the project and run it with the CUDA debugger? The "Local Windows Debugger" button shouldn't be used, right?

Anyways, here is my code:

Vector.cuh

```
#pragma once

#ifdef __CUDACC__
#define CUDA_CALLABLE_MEMBER __host__ __device__
#else
#define CUDA_CALLABLE_MEMBER
#endif 

#include <iostream>
class Vector4
{
public:
    float x, y, z, w;
    CUDA_CALLABLE_MEMBER Vector4();
    CUDA_CALLABLE_MEMBER Vector4(float x, float y, float z, float w);
    CUDA_CALLABLE_MEMBER virtual ~Vector4();
    CUDA_CALLABLE_MEMBER void print();
    CUDA_CALLABLE_MEMBER Vector4 operator+(const Vector4& other);
    CUDA_CALLABLE_MEMBER void add(Vector4* other);
};
```

Part of Vector.cu

```
Vector4::Vector4(float x, float y, float z, float w)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->z = z;
    this->w = w;
}
Vector4 Vector4::operator+(const Vector4 & other)
{
    return Vector4( 
                    this->x + other.x,
                    this->y + other.y,
                    this->z + other.z,
                    this->w + other.w
                  );
}
```

main.cu

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda.h>
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "Vector.cuh"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

__global__ void addVector(Vector4* a, Vector4* b)
{
    (*a) = (*a) + (*b);
    //a->x += 1;
}

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    int size = sizeof(Vector4);
    Vector4 v(1, 0, 0, 0);
    Vector4 b(1, 1, 0, 0);

    Vector4* d_v;
    Vector4* d_b;

    //cudaMalloc the device pointers
    //cudaMalloc(&pointer, bytes)
    cudaMalloc(&d_v, size);
    cudaMalloc(&d_b, size);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }


        //cudaMemcpy the pointers to actual host data
        //cudaMemcpy(to, from, bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)
        cudaMemcpy(d_v, &v, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaMemcpy(d_b, &b, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


        cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();
        HANDLE_ERROR(err);

        //call kernel with the new device data
        addVector << <1, 1 >> >(d_v, d_b);

        //cudaMemcpy back to the old host variables
        //cudaMemcpy(to, from, bytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost)
        cudaMemcpy(&v, d_v, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        cudaMemcpy(&b, d_b, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

        v.print();
        b.print();
        printf("\n\n");
        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }


    //cudaFree
    cudaFree(d_v);
    cudaFree(d_b);
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Also here's the command line code under CUDA C++ in the project settings:

```
set CUDAFE_FLAGS=--sdk_dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\"
"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin\nvcc.exe" --use-local-env --cl-version 2015 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64"     -G   --keep-dir x64\Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static  -g    -Xcompiler "/EHsc  /nologo  /FS /Zi   " -o x64\Debug\%(Filename)%(Extension).obj "%(FullPath)"
```

Sorry for the wall of text, thanks!

**EDIT:**
I'm using CUDA 8.0

Comment: Also for the person that downvoted, may I know why?

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't compile.

There is no definition of `__device__ _ZN7Vector4plERKS_`  (i.e. `__device__ Vector4::operator+(Vector4 const&)` ) anywhere I can see. And when you fix that, you will either need to enable separate device code compilation and linking, or import Vector.cu into main.cu, because the device code for the operator isn't defined in the same translation unit as the kernel which calls it.

Comment: Simply importing Vector.cu solved the problem, but it isn't ideal as my project gets larger. Can you shed some light on that separate device code compilation part? I found this [link](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/separate-compilation-linking-cuda-device-code/) but, it didn't work, since I mostly don't know which settings of the project to alter.